# Remove duplicates leaving the one with the most current date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge Excel table (13,000+ rows) containing account numbers and different dates, with some of the account numbers repeated.

I wish to only keep the account numbers with the most recent dates and delete the duplicates with the older dates.

[image]

Comment: Create Pivot table based on your data with account as category and MAX(date) as data. Copy-PasteSpecial the result to the place you need.

Comment: You have two date columns which one you want to use for most current date as criteria ?

Comment: Since you are dealing with 13000 records so that  MACRO would be the best & fastest option, if you are comfortable just confirm, I can suggest one to you !!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution just requires sorting and the use of the `Remove Duplicates` tool.

First, perform this two-level sort using `Data`→`Sort & Filter`→`Sort` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>):

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing the Two-Level Sort]

Level 1: Sort by the account number on `Values` ordered by `Smallest to Largest`
Level 2: Sort by the date on `Values` ordered by `Newest to Oldest`

Note that two separate sorts will also work (first by the date, and then by the account number). This is quicker, especially if Filter Mode is already turned on.

Then, use the `Data`→`Data Tools`→`Remove Duplicates` tool (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>):

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing the Remove Duplicates Tool]

Make sure that only the account number column is selected.

This is the result:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot of the Result]

This works because the Remove Duplicates tool keeps the topmost row of each set of duplicates.